# Print Report to File Microsoft Dynamics AX 4.0

Tags: axapta

I've created and run a report in Microsoft Dynamics AX 4.0. I'm now looking to "Print" the report to a txt file so I can do some manual calculations based on it. When I select "File" from the "Send to" options, a File Format drop down is presented, but only PDF is available. What do I need to do to enable the other export options?

[image]

I also face the same limitations if I click the report, then select options before I create the report:

[image]

The odd part is some of the users are able to export to other file formats. Can this be related to using a 32 bit vs a 64 bit client?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to check in the AOT if `\Forms\SysPrintForm` has been modified. You might find something like `FileFormat.allowEdit(false);` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your screenshot, there is no "screen" option. This implies to me you have printed to screen first. Do you get any different options for exports if you try to print DIRECTLY to a file format?